# How can I fix "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" on function in Swift using FirebaseFirestoreSwift?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

```
func fetchUser() {
  guard let uid = userSession?.uid else { return }

  Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, _ in
    guard let user = try? snapshot?.data(as: User.self) else { return }
    self.currentUser = user
 }
}
```

The error is thrown on the "guard let user" line. Any idea on how to fix this error? Also, I am not using Cocoapods ... I am using Firebase from the github sdk

Comment: Do you mean "no arguments"? Which line is highlighted with the error?

Comment: Oops, yes ... I mean "no arguments". The error is on the "guard let user" line

Comment: Are you sure that you've imported "FirebaseFirestoreSwift" at the top of the file?

Comment: did you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that you have:

```
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
```

With this the data(as: ) function, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are missing the "documents" step, could you try something like this:

```
func fetchUser() {
    guard let uid = userSession?.uid else { return }
    
    Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, _ in
        guard let docs = snapshot else { return }
        for doc in docs.documents {
            let user = doc.data(as: User.self)
            self.currentUser = user
            // break as required or just get the first in documents
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using the Firebase sdk from github and not Cocoapods. The above code threw another error: "Value of type 'DocumentSnapshot' has no member 'documents'"