# Argument passed to call that takes no arguments for Firebase Swift Integration

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is my function:

```
private func sync() {
    guard userIsAuthenticated else { return }
    db.collection("users").document(self.uuid!).getDocument { (document, error) in
        guard let document = document, document.exists, error == nil else {
            return
        }
        do {
            if let user = try document.data(as: User.self) {
                self.user = user
            }
        } catch {
            print("Sync error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

It takes place at:

```
if let user = try document.data(as: User.self) {
    self.user = user
}
```

This is my podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Carpooly' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Carpooly
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
  
  target 'CarpoolyTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'CarpoolyUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I have no idea how to fix the error any help is much appreciated thank you!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68824752/how-can-i-fix-argument-passed-to-call-that-takes-no-arguments-on-function-in-s

Comment: What version of the Firebase iOS package have you added to your project?

Comment: I should be using the latest version. I have edited my code above to include my podfile.

Comment: Update: I am using Firebase iOS version 10.19.0